# Logstash read line that doesnt end with EOL

Tags: buffer, logstash, delimiter, multiline, codec

I am processing an ancient .xml log file schema that cannot be changed it is a legacy thing and it would be too expensive to fix the issues.

The issues are:

1. The file root element is  but it may never be closed -> so I cant just set file => { ... delimiter => "" } to read this xml object
2. The children element all have unique names   ...  ... -> the best idea I have had by now is to create 11 file plugins one with the delimiter = "" and other 10 that would match "0>" ... "9>" it ***should*** work but I am concerned with the should part.
3. last issue is that after the last line of the element there is not "\n" so I cant just use multiline to merge the lines neither

My question is someone familiar with a way to flush the content of the logstash's internal buffer in which incomplete lines are stored and then manipulate that data, this would solve my issue in much better and more performant way.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you add a preprocessing step before logstash in order to make the XML file somewhat standard?

Comment: well technically yes, practically no, since it is a dedicated machine with a server, it wouldnt be cost effective to add yet another process that will consume resources, and the server is not to be changed :/ I am kinda in a messy situation :/